# How to fetch icon file from provided URL

Tags: php, fetch, favicon

Help me by providing some easy steps.

**URL like:** www.facebook.com
How could  i fetch facebook icon.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you want to get it or what?

Comment: You mean the http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yv/r/aWMatkshsiW.png one? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: I am building website where user will enter url. I want favicon must be fetch automatically

Comment: The favicon is everyone's favorite icon.

Answer (score 2):

First, try to retrieve `favicon.ico` in the root directory, which would be http://www.facebook.com/favicon.ico in this case.

If that doesn't work, retrieve the homepage and look for one of these HTML tags in the content:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="someurl" />
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="someurl" />
```

Sometimes, favicon.ico does exist, though the `<link>` tag is missing.

Comment: +1 for suggesting at least trying the usual location first. )

Comment: @raina77ow +1 for upvoting him for looking at default location first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
<?php 
$url = 'http://example.com/';
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = FALSE;
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
$arr = $xml->xpath('//link[@rel="shortcut icon"]');
echo $arr[0]['href'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dl the homepage of FB parse it through something like http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php and search for the link tag with a rel attribute of icon. With this you can then curl the file down and use it for display links etc.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get page content (best method I could suggest is via cURL)
2. Parse HTML or perform regular expression matching. Look for the `link` tag with attribute `rel="shortcut icon"` or `rel="icon"`. Extract `href` value from this tag. Here is an example link tag from FB: `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/yi/r/q9U99v3_saj.ico" />`